# orderByChild().equalTo() is always null in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get some data of Firebase. I'm tring to do orderby().equalTo() but I'm always getting null in my query. I've tried with two values deliveredBy (boolean) and deliveredBy (long).

**Query**

```
 queryFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("rooms").orderByChild("read").equalTo(false);
        queryFirebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

**Send my message to Firebase**

```
Long userId = ApplicationConfig.getCurrentUser().getId();
            String toServerUnicodeEncoded = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(etMessage.getText().toString());
            MessageFirebase message = new MessageFirebase(toServerUnicodeEncoded, new DateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"), userId);
            DatabaseReference messageRef = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.push();
            messageRef.setValue(message);
```

**MY JSON**

```
{
  "rooms" : {
    "-KtMBWKEf7-Ot8HdMtbd" : {
      "-KtMC7CglZZ-Yp4_PQOU" : {
        "blocked" : false,
        "createDate" : "2017-09-06T14:40:17Z",
        "delivered" : false,
        "deliveredBy" : 317,
        "difDays" : 0,
        "isBlocked" : false,
        "message" : "hola",
        "read" : false
      },
      "-KtMCCdbKzP7UKFTB_qG" : {
        "blocked" : false,
        "createDate" : "2017-09-06T14:40:39Z",
        "delivered" : false,
        "deliveredBy" : 317,
        "difDays" : 0,
        "isBlocked" : false,
        "message" : "que tal",
        "read" : false
      },
      "commerceId" : 218,
      "userId" : 317
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` is not a direct child of `rooms`

You should do

```
queryFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("rooms")
    .child("-KtMBWKEf7-Ot8HdMtbd")
    .orderByChild("read")
    .equalTo(false);
queryFirebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

Comment: Yes, but I assume that I don't know what's my child("-KtMBWKEf7-Ot8HdMtbd").

Comment: Your data is probably structured incorrectly than. Why do you have "KtMBWKEf7-Ot8HdMtbd" as a key? What does it represent? A room name?

Comment: I'm doing a chat the first key represent the chat room and the second one: "KtMBWKEf7-Ot8HdMtbd" is a message of one user in this room

Comment: I assume you 'do' know/have the chat-room key (first key in the hierarchy) when querying the data. Just add this to the path as @Mariano suggested.